# Update JwtBearerOptions After Startup

Tags: c#, authentication, jwt, asp.net-core-mvc

In my program, I have my `ConfigureServices` method in startup.

Within that function I have this:

```cs
services.AddAuthentication(auth => {
  auth.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
  auth.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer(options => {
  options.SaveToken = true;
  options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents() {
    OnAuthenticationFailed = c => {
      Console.WriteLine("Auth Failed");
      return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
  };
  options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters {
    ValidateIssuer = true,
      ValidIssuer = AppSettings.SignInSettings.IdentityUrl,
      ValidateAudience = false,
      //ValidAudience = config.JwtToken.Audience,
      ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
      //IssuerSigningKeys = new JsonWebKeySet(jwks).GetSigningKeys()
  };
});
```

My `IssuerSigningKeys` value is obtained from my identity server through `.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks`.

The issue I am having is how do I get that value and set it to my `JwtBearerOptions` after startup has completed? I have to make the http call to get the values after startup as the service is not available in `ConfigureServices`.

I have tried

> lifetime.ApplicationStarted.Register(OnApplicationStartedAsync(clientFactory,
> appSettings, options).Wait);

which does let me get the value right after startup, but I don't see a way to update the config value itself. I can retrieve the current value via `IOptionsMonitor<JwtBearerOptions>`. Can I configure `JwtBearerOptions` in my startup's `Configure` method?

---

Edit: I will post an answer if this works, but I think the best solution is to propagate the x509 cert I need on the identity server to the other app servers so I can just reference it on startup.

Comment: Hi @Jeff B, I think a more common way is to store these value in appsettings.json and you could get them by Configuration.

Comment: @Rena Thanks, I do this for most things. The issue is that these keys can change day over day on the identity server. If I kept these values in app settings then I would have to update that value on every application every time it changed, and the entire app would break until the change was made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to change how I was trying to accomplish this.
There is no way to set that `IssuerSigningKey` dynamically.

The solution I ended up going with was to no longer worry about verifying the `SigningKey` on the client application and do introspection on the API instead. This is because the user gains nothing if the `SigningKey` is invalid on the UI. The most they would gain is being able to see buttons or other elements that would normally be hidden, but the data would never return.